# Is a left-side tab close button in Firefox possible?

Tags: macos, firefox

The tab close button in Firefox is on the right side.  But that feels weird in macOS, where all close buttons are on the left side.  Is it possible to move it to the left side, possibly with an extension or a configuration setting?

[image: left-side close buttons]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As luck would have it, [the Firefox UI can be customized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) in `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<PROFILE_ID>/chrome/userChrome.css`.  Add the following to that file (valid for Firefox v98):

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

.tabbrowser-tab .tab-throbber,
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-icon-image,
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-sharing-icon-overlay,
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-icon-overlay,
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-label-container,
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-icon-sound {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2 !important;
}
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-label-container {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-icon-image {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.tabbrowser-tab .tab-close-button {
  margin-left: -5px !important;
  margin-right: 2.5px !important;
}
.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned="true"]):hover .tab-close-button {
  display: -moz-box !important;
}
.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned="true"]):hover .tab-icon-stack,
.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned="true"]):hover .tab-throbber,
.tab-close-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Also, [userChrome.css is disabled by default in Firefox 69+](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/), so go to `about:config` and set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true`

Thanks to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1157451 for inspiration. I've also [added a Gist with this info](https://gist.github.com/henrik242/3abf4c52ebf81add5cfe38acf97c2053).

Comment: "Also, userChrome.css is disabled by default in Firefox 69+"... _this_ is the information nobody mentions anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update this for the new Proton interface? It still works, but it is a little wonky.

Comment: @stommestack Could you elaborate a bit? It looks fine to me (Firefox Developer Edition v91.0b6)

Comment: @neu242 Here’s what it looks like for me on hovering (the dot on the left is the loading indicator) https://i.postimg.cc/C12gT5Lk/Schermafbeelding-2021-07-23-om-12-00-27.png

Comment: @stommestack Weird, I don't see that here at all. I suggest enabling Browser Toolbox and tweaking the margin-left/right attributes yourself.

Comment: I have the same issue as @stommestack, from a fresh install. I'm using Firefox for Mac 94.0.1 (64-bit). Could you tell how to use _Browser Toolbox_ to fix this?

Comment: @Kwadz Here's some info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox